# How to get local date time for timezone

Tags: java, date, time

Here is the problem

I get the data from API as

```
curl "http://api.timezonedb.com/?lat=53.7833&lng=-1.75&key=OXFVZEHUDERF&format=json"
{"status":"OK","message":"","countryCode":"GB","zoneName":"Europe\/London","abbreviation":"BST","gmtOffset":"3600","dst":"1","timestamp":1442983759}Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:~ harit$ curl "http://api.timezonedb.com/?lat=-44.490947&lng=171.220966&key=API_KEY&format=json"
```

and result as

```
{"status":"OK","message":"","countryCode":"NZ","zoneName":"Pacific\/Auckland","abbreviation":"NZST","gmtOffset":"43200","dst":"0","timestamp":1443023417}
```

As per their [docs](http://timezonedb.com/api), the `timestamp` is

> Current local time in Unix timestamp.

How do I print it as

```
2013-07-10T14:52:49
```

in that timezone `Europe/London` ?

Answer (score 0):

Though you have not mentioned but you can achieve it in java 8 like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    final long unixTime = 1443023417;
    final String formattedDtm = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("PLT")).format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDtm);   
    }
```

It prints:
`2015-09-23 11:50:17`

Java 8 introduces the [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) method for creating an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from a Unix timestamp which can then be converted to a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and then can be formatted as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the timezone as well timestamp, you can get LocalDateTime as

```
LocalDateTime lt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp), ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("BST")));
System.out.println(lt);
```